# How to efficiently combine multiple small files present in multiple S3 location

Tags: amazon-web-services, java-8, aws-lambda, amazon-emr

I have a usecase where we have to combine multiple small small files (many a times less than 5MB) present at multiple S3 locations. We tried doing it using Java, EMR/spark but the time taken to do the task is very long. Eg to combine 7000 files present at a single location, spark took 1.5 to 2 mins. I know 7000 is a very small number and spark is not ideal solution to do the same. Any suggestion for any java/aws technology to solve my usecase.

Comment: hmm, this is an interesting use case. I wonder if you could copy all the file locations into a temporary redshift table and then do an unload on the table back into a consolidated s3 location? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing new aspect to solve the problem. Is unload option is only supported by Redshift or we can use any other data base/ data store to use this operation?